# Discrete space and time one-dimensional walk

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> A person is standing on $0$ on the $x$-axis at $t=0$. After each second, the person can either move one unit to the right (with probability $a$), move one unit to the left (with probability $b$), or stay where he is (with probability $1-a-b$). Find the probability that, at time $T$, the person is at $+d$ on the $x$-axis?

**My try :**

Let $P(x,t)$ be the probability that the person is at $x$ at time $t$. Then the following holds good : $$P(x,t)=a\cdot P(x-1,t-1)+b\cdot P(x+1,t-1)+(1-a-b)\cdot P(x,t-1)$$

With the initial conditions $P(0,0)=1$, $P(1,0)=0$ and $P(0,1)=1-a-b$.

How do I solve this recurrence relation using a generating function? I know how to solve one variable recursions using a generating function, but what about this?

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Got something from the answer?

Comment: @Did Definitely! Big thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating function approach is to consider $G(s,t)=\sum\limits_xP(x,t)s^x$ for every $t\geqslant0$ and to note that $G(s,0)=1$ and $G(s,t+1)=(as+bs^{-1}+1-a-b)\cdot G(s,t)$ for every $t\geqslant0$ hence $$G(s,t)=(as+bs^{-1}+1-a-b)^t.$$ 
Each $P(x,t)$ is the coefficient of $s^x$ in $G(s,t)$. Various formulas for $P(x,t)$ as a sum can be deduced, for example, introducing $c=ab(1-a-b)^{-2}$, for every $|x|\leqslant t$, $$P(x,t)=a^x(1-a-b)^{t-x}\sum_j\frac{t!\,c^j}{j!(j+x)!(t-x-2j)!}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x+j\leqslant x+2j\leqslant t}.$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit more of your last step, starting with the substitution?

Comment: Sure--could you be more specific about the part needing more explanations?

Comment: The part where you substituted $c=ab(1-a-b)^{-2}$ and the summation notation at the end.

Comment: Simply use the algebraic identity $$(u+v+w)^t=\sum_{i,j}\frac{t!\,u^iv^jw^{t-i-j}}{i!j!(t-i-j)!},$$ for $u=as$, $v=bs^{-1}$, $w=1-a-b$, and collect the terms $s^x$ in the RHS, which are exactly those such that $i-j=x$.